# Cannot get Tumblr Javascript to work

Tags: javascript, html, json, tumblr

I am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://underlineent.tumblr.com/api/read/json">
</script>
```

To get my Tumblr blog onto this site and it is not working. Can someone help?

The link is tumblr's api of fetching a tumblr blog through javascript. On their api site it says that is all i need to fetch the blog. I am wondering if i made a stupid mistake or if godaddy blocks javascript or something of the sort.

Comment: This isn't a question we can answer, it is a request for general assistance. Either rephrase this as a concrete request for help with a specific technical problem, or address it to a consultant web developer. No doubt many of the users here are available for hire.

Comment: oh boy, here comes the flame.

You might want to try explaining the issue a little better, code examples and more detailed explanation of what you are seeing will help - are you seeing any specific errors?

Comment: Please don't post links to your website.  It makes you look like a spammer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<script type="text/javascript" src="underlineent.tumblr.com/api/read/json"></script>`

You want an external script reference instead. This one looks locally.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://underlineent.tumblr.com/api/read/json"></script>`

Prepending with "http://" gets the real URL rather then the local one.

Your asking tumblr to load your data into a local variable. There is absolutely no javascript on the page to manipulate said local variable. You need to include (probably something from tumblr) javascript to manipulate `tumblr_api_read`

As you can see at their [API docs](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api) you need to manipulate the data manually.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var posts = tumblr_api_read.posts;
    for (var i = 0, len = posts.length; i < len; i++) {
         var div = document.createNode("div");
         div.innerHTML = posts[i]["video-player"];
         document.body.appendChild(div);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: That was a stupid mistake in my copy and pasting, I have fixed that to no avail, for some reason it just wont work. I am using go daddy as a hosting service if that helps.

Comment: @freakingdean you need to render your JSON data.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the contents of what is being served at http://underlineent.tumblr.com/api/read/json - it's just a bunch of json being stuck in a variable. You need to do something with that data to render it to the page.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the link you are using is relative, take your url out and add http in front of it. also, you may need to use jsonp to get the data.